# How to define existing API gateway project to be used for deployment in serverless.yml?

Tags: serverless-framework, angular-universal, aws-serverless

I'm using `serverless` framework for deployment of angular-universal app (aws lambda + API gateway). Every time I run the deployment from a different PC or just define a new stage, serverless automatically creates a new API gateway project in aws.

```
# serverless.yml

# generated by @ng-toolkit/serverless
service: web-app

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 20
  apiName: ssr-web-app

package:
  exclude:
   - src/**
   - node_modules/**
   - firebug-lite/**
   - e2e/**
   - coverage/**
   - '!node_modules/aws-serverless-express/**'
   - '!node_modules/binary-case/**'
   - '!node_modules/type-is/**'
   - '!node_modules/media-typer/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-types/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-db/**'

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'

functions:
  api:
    handler: lambda.universal
    events:
      - http: ANY {proxy+}
      - http: ANY /
```

I want that every time I run a deployment `serverless` would always use the same specific `gateway API` project, creating new stages under the same defined project.
How can I define a reference to the existing `gateway API` project (id?) in my `serverless.yml`?

---- EDIT ----
I tried to add to `provider` section the following:

```
apiGateway: 
   restApiId: xxxxxxxxxx 
   restApiRootResourceId: yyyyyyyyyy
```

and got an error "An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourceProxyVar - Another resource with the same parent already has this name: {proxy+} "

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

In order to share existing API Gateways, you'll need to declare the associated `restApiId` in your `serverless.yml` file, along with the `restApiRootResourceId`.

You can read more in the [docs, here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#share-api-gateway-and-api-resources).
You can also follow this [excellent blog post](https://www.gorillastack.com/news/splitting-your-serverless-framework-api-on-aws/)

Comment: I tried to add to `provider` section the following:
```
apiGateway:
      restApiId: xxxxxxxxxx
      restApiRootResourceId: yyyyyyyyyy
```
and got an error  "An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourceProxyVar - Another resource with the same parent already has this name: {proxy+} "

Comment: If you're going to share an API Gateway, you cannot have two separate functions claiming the same route, in your case `ANY {proxy+}`.

You'll need to configure a base path, for example
Lambda 1:
```
functions:
  api:
    handler: lambda.universal
    events:
      - http: /universal/{proxy+}
```
and then Lambda 2:
```
functions:
  api2:
    handler: lambda.universal2
    events:
      - http: /universal2/{proxy+}
```